# Delayed Job Error Hook

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, delayed-job

Is the Delayed Job error hook fired once when the job first has an error or it is fired each time the job has errors on the retries too. My code seems to be firing the hook once on the 1st error and it doesn't fire on the retries errors?

Answer (score 1):

`error` hook fires after every failed attempt, while `failure` fires once after number of attempts is greater than `max_attempts`.

If the `error` is running only once, check for:

1. `max_attempts` is set to one. Try explicitly setting the max attempts:

   ```
   def max_attempts
      3   
   end
   ```
2. You have an exception in your `error` hook. Try adding a rescue clause:

   ```
   def error
       # your code
   rescue => e
       Rails.logger.error "houston we have a problem #{e.message}"
   end
   ```